# print boolean True results of a regex match-Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This may be a simple question, but couldn't figure out how to perform. I have a pandas dataframe with following columns.

```
df.columns = ['IP', 'Time', 'Method', 'Resource', 'Status', 'Bytes', 'Referrer', 'Agent']
```

I want to do some regex match to df['Resource'] column. I did it in the flowing way.

```
df.Resource.str.contains('pdf')
```

Then I need to print only the 'True' results with df['IP'], df['Time'], and df['Resource']. How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have to use na=false so missing values can be considered True or False according to [pandas-docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#basics-string-methods). This worked fine.

```
print df[df.Resource.str.contains('pdf',na=False)][['IP', 'Time', 'Resource']][0:5]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding, this should work.

```
df[df.Resource.str.contains('pdf')][['IP', 'Time', 'Resource']]
```

Basically, it's using a mask to limit the rows in `df` to only those that return `True`, then it's only giving you columns: `IP`, `Time`, `Resource`.

Comment: It gives "ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values". I tried with fillna(0)? Same Error is given. Do you have any idea?

Comment: In your answer how do we chech for "True" values?

Comment: `df.Resource.str.contains('pdf')` returns a boolean value predicated on if the string contains `'pdf'`.

Comment: Yes! Thanks! We have to use na=false!

Comment: Makes sense, next time you might specify that you have `na`s so the person who answers knows that that's a requirement.

Comment: Sure!..Sorry for the inconvenience!